# ReactJs Functional Component: useState behavior on updating the state with same value

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, react-state

I am little confused how react state works in react functional components.
Internet says in the most basic scenario for primitive states,

- Functional Component will not re-render incase the state is same as before
- For Class Component it will re-render regardless

But for following code below, using functional component, I am facing below scenario:

First Time when the state changes, the component is re-rendered

If again I update the state with same value, the state again changes

All the afterward attempts of updating the state with same value does not re-render the component.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  console.log("Component Ran");
  const [placeHolder, setPlaceHolder] = useState("Start");
  const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains("state")) return;
    const it = e.target.innerText;
    console.log("coming from onClickHandler", it);
    setPlaceHolder(it);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>{placeHolder}</div>
      <div onClick={onClickHandler}>
        <button className="state">State 1</button>
        <button className="state">State 2</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Basically there are two buttons, each respectively for sate 1 and 2. When the button is clicked the state placeHolder is updated with button's `innerText` . On top of the button there is element which displays the state.
Below is what I noticed in console:
Let's say now the placeHolder state is state 1.
I click on state 2 button, I get below output in console log.

coming from onClickHandler State 2

Component Ran

Again I click on button with state 2
and again I get same output.

But next time and for the million times after that when I click the button with state 2, I only get below output,

coming from onClickHandler State 2

What am I missing here.
At very least I expect one kind of behavior, either the component is re-rendered every time regardless or it does only when it changes. Why this mixed behaiour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to behave as expected.  Clicking the "State 1" button logs `coming from onClickHandler State 1`, and clicking the "State 2" button logs `coming from onClickHandler State 2`.

See the sandbox here to verify:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lamport-2tfe8m?file=/src/App.js